# navigation by action for p:menuitem doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am currently using PrimeFaces 5.

I have this method in a bean called home:

```java
public String panelSearch() {
   pnlsearch = true;
   return "home";           
}
```

`pnlsearch` is a property that makes a panel visible

**home.xhtml** contains:

```xhtml
<p:menubar>
   <p:menuitem id="mnusearch" 
               value="Search"
               ajax="true"
               action="#{home.panelSearch}"
               icon="ui-icon-search" />

     <p:menuitem  value="Search"   >
        <p:commandLink  ajax="false"

                       action="#{home.panelSearch}"
                      value="Search" />
    </p:menuitem>    
</p:menubar>

<h:panelGrid rendered="#{home.pnlsearch}">...</h:panelGrid>
```

`panelSearch` is called with action in both  `p:menuitem` and in `p:commandLink`
but `panelSearch` is visible only with `p:commandLink`

Why `panelSearch` is not made visible with a click on `p:menuitem` alone as well?

note: `p:commandLink` is called no matter the navigation-rule in faces-config.xml

Comment: in the commandLink what do you mean by `ajax="true|false"` ?

Comment: @Hatem: That's not `true` and totally explains why it "works" in this construct.

Comment: @Hatem removed but the problem remains

Comment: @BalusC is it a valid value ? it looks confusing for me. And yes if it's not `true` as you said, it would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @Hatem: it's just evaluated as `false`, because it's not `true`.

Comment: Why didn't you retest the code and revise the question after removing that attribute? You're now basically lying in the question by stating that it works with the given `<p:commandLink>`.

Comment: Yes BalusC you are right. Now  commandLink has the Ajax="false"  attribute. Anyway, my problem is that the action attribute on <p:menuitem doesn't work.